# Как в yii в шапку добавить элемент из БД?

Tags: yii

Здравствуйте, мне нужно в шапку в шаблоне main.php прикрепить номер телефона из БД, не могу собразить, как это сделать. Отдельный модуль создать или как-то по-другому можно вытащить?

Конечно, могу просто так между блок написать номер телефона, но тогда если номер изменится, то пользователь сайта не сможет изменить номер на сайте.

Comment: вместо того чтобы получить нормальный ответ получил куче минусов, товарищи, вы хоть подсказки оставлили хотя бы

Answer (score 4):

Документацию читать не пробовали?

- [Основы /
     Представление](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/basics.view)
- [Работа с БД / Конструктор
     запросов](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.query-builder)

P.S. Цитирую фрагмент из главы "Основы / Представление":

Кроме того, мы можем использовать следующий способ для передачи данных представлению:

```
$this->render('edit', array(
    'var1'=>$value1,
    'var2'=>$value2,
));
```

В приведённом коде метод render() преобразует второй параметр — массив — в переменные. Как результат, внутри представления будут доступны локальные переменные `$var1` и `$var2`.

Comment: Документацию прочитал, но севсем понял как это сделать, как вырвать из бд понял, а как вот в шапку прикрепить элемент из бд не могу понять

Comment: Специально для вас процитировал кусок из документации.

Comment: )) ааа, понял

Comment: Разобрался, Не самый лучший ответ, в таком случаю $var1 и $var2 Доступны только в edit.php, а мне нужно чтоб переменная везде доступна была. Ваш вариант не помог!

Comment: А вы попробуйте всё-таки почитать документацию. Во всяком случае на той же странице есть как минимум описание виджетов...

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю тут нужен виджет. вот [пример](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/blog/ru/portlet.comments)